# View calendar if there is an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on a site for a friend, and was wondering if there was a way to check if there is an event for today in the jQuery plugin [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). And if there is some event today, then display basicDay calendar, otherwise hide the calendar? Or, failing that, have it able to focus basicDay calendar on the next event in the calendar, if there is one.

Comment: Suggest you read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post your code

Comment: @Sumeet you are asking something very vague. The short answer is Yes what you are probably asking is possible. The problem is you are asking so many things it seems like you want us to do the work for you. Do you want to code something from scratch? Are there any third party libraries that you can use and that help you accomplish your task? What is your data gonna be like? Where and how will the events be stored and read.... are all questions you should be asking yourself before starting to code your project

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
// Initiate a variable that tells that there is no event today
var hasAnEventToday = false;

//We'll create a variable for today
var today = new Date();

//First, you store your events in a variable
var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

// Loop trough the event to see if there is at least one with your date
$.each(events, function(){ 
  var testedDate = new Date($(this)[0].start._i); 
  if (today == testedDate){
    hasAnEventToday = true;
  }
});

if (hasAnEventToday){
   // Do your logic
}
```